# how to redirect_to another page in my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, routes

When my user signs up, it originally gets redirected to its blank profile page.

However, I need the user to be redirected to a additional info page in order to retrieve more information

My users controller looks like this

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController

 def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end

 def new
   @user = User.new
  end


  def additional_info
    @user = User.new
  end


def create
 @user = User.new(user_params)
 if @user.save
  UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
  sign_in @user
  redirect_to users: 'additional_info'
  flash[:success] = "Welcome to InYourShoes!"
  return @user       
 else
   render'new'
 end
```

end

```
private

def user_params 
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

end

As you can see, additional_info is the other page I'm trying to redirect to. I'm aware that I create 2 users objects, but I'm not sure if its correct. Frankly speaking I'm kind of lost.

my routes for the pages is this:

```
resources :users
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
match '/additionalinfo',to: 'users#additional_info', via: 'get'
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in yours routes

```
match '/additionalinfo',to: 'users#additional_info', via: 'get', as: :additional_info
```

in controller

```
redirect_to additional_info_path
```

Comment: Better to use `get`, since Rails 4 deprecates `match`. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: can you explain the part as: :additional_info ? is it because the way I defined it in my userController?

Comment: 'as' is use to give name to any routes. you can give as: :info then  your path will become info_path.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can change the redirect line to:

```
redirect_to action: 'additional_info'
```

Assuming you have the action defined in your routes:

```
get :additional_info, to: 'users#additional_info' # use get rather than match
```

Comment: can you explain the benefits of doing get vs match?

Comment: Rails 4 deprecate it. [Here](http://homakov.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/whitelist-your-routes-match-is-evil.html) a good article exposing some problems using `match`: security, bad practices, no RESTful ...

Comment: Try to restart the server or check if any before_filter is causing `no route match`. I tried in a Rails 3.2 app and it works perfectly. Can you paste the full error message?